# Change image after click on ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

everyone. After clicking on an ImageView, I would like to change it depending on what kind of drawable is currently displayed. To do this, I compare the currently set image in the ImageView with one from the drawable folder. Unfortunately, it is currently the case that only the else branch is executed. The image changes after the first click, but then it no longer switches. What am I doing wrong?

```
 bookmark_site.setOnClickListener{
        vibrator.vibrate(50);

        var draw = bookmark_site.drawable.constantState


        if(draw == ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_baseline_bookmark_filled_24)?.constantState)
        {
            bookmark_site.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_outline_bookmark_border_outline_24))
        }
        else{

         //Only this two is ever executed
            bookmark_site.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_bookmark_filled_24))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't base on `constantState`, its not desired to compare drawables as there is a different instance for every drawable, thus your `if` isn't `true` never ever. in fact there is no way for getting resource of drawable already set for `ImageView`. most convenient way would be to keep some boolean flag outside `onClick` method informing that image is switched or not. optionally you may keep this flag "inside" `ImageView` using [`setTag(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setTag(java.lang.Object)) method

```
bookmark_site.setOnClickListener{
    vibrator.vibrate(50);

    val switched = bookmark_site.tag != null
    
    bookmark_site.setImageResource(
        if (switched) R.drawable.ic_outline_bookmark_border_outline_24
        else R.drawable.ic_baseline_bookmark_filled_24
    )
    
    bookmark_site.tag = if (switched) null else "SWITCHED"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should keep category or tag along with the image in the model class and then change the image on the basis of that tag or category.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).